# Who owns this patent?

Tags: business

In reference to the patent: [US8780542](https://www.google.com/patents/US8780542)

USI-Tech is claiming a patent on a similar sounding technology, see link, do they now own this technology?

https://www.bitcoincoaches.com/energy-creation-recyclable-energy-new-techcoin-among-major-usi-tech-announcements/

Answer (score 1):

The assignee for the patent you cited is EMC. While it is possible USI-Tech took a license or purchased that patent outright, I think it is more likely they are pursuing a different approach to a similar problem. Although the title of a patent may seem general in scope, the actual protected technology is described in the claims and should be quite specific. There are often alternative solutions to the same problem. Each alternative solution can potentially get its own patent.

Answer (score -1):

They will have IP rights over this technology if the patent is granted.

Sometimes Applicants have merely a patent application but they announce it as the patent has already been granted.

To know if they have the patent granted, go to USPTO site and search by Applicant.